# Cog command duplicates messages (Discord.py Rewrite)

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm making an economy bot and this is the first time I've used Cogs.
For some reason, every time I trigger a command it sends more than one message. I've also seen a pattern where for every command the amount of messages sent is one more than the previous command.

Here is my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

import json

class currencyCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
   
    global currency
    with open('cogs/data/currency.json') as f:
        currency = json.load(f)

    def _save(self):
        with open('cogs/data/currency.json', 'w+') as f:
            json.dump(currency, f)

    async def new_user(self, id:int):
        currency[str(id)] = {
            "cash": 100,
            "multi": 1,
            "upgrades": {
                "click_max": 100
            },
            "items": {
                "beginner-crate": 1
            }
        }
        self._save()
        user = self.bot.get_user(id)
        await user.send('message')

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_command(self, ctx):
        id = ctx.author.id
        if str(id) in currency:
            pass
        else:
            await self.new_user(id)


    @commands.command()
    async def test(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send('beep')
```

Note: I have no other instances of the bot running. I'm using Sublime text 3's python build to run my code.

Output:
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCIiH.png)

Comment: Can you please attach an image or example of what the output is?

Comment: There. I've edited the post. (It's at the very bottom)

Comment: I don't see how your code could possibly generate the output you posted. The "Cogs are working" string is nowhere to be found

Comment: Not reproducible, works fine in my bot.

Comment: @LukasThaler I added that string to a command earlier then replaced it with 'beep'. Also, I believe I've found the error. I checked my task manager and found 12 instances of Python 3.8 running... Should I delete the post or post an answer? (Sorry I'm new to stack overflow)

Comment: This is very unlikely to be of value to a future reader. I'd advocate for deleting it (else it'll probably be closed as "not reproducible" anyway)

Comment: @w4ffle_bread it did solve my problem, so maybe don't delete it. For me it happened when I deleted an old command from one cog to another, so maybe the old instances were sending the old commands I had.